# Which jar on weblogic server/ other resources could possibly have class: oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I wanted to know which jar do have this class file :

oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter

Our deployment is working fine on test system, but failed on production saying class not found : oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter

We have made this entry in our web.xml, but we are not able to find the jar which is present in our test system , but not present in our production system.

Please let me know possibles jar/s which might have this class :

oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter

Comment: How is deployed your application? War or EAR? Check this [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/common_pitfalls_when_deploying)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Found out this Jar file it is : jps-ee.jar and in my system its on location here :

C:\Oracle_11g\Middleware\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps_11.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Available in [Oracle's Maven repo](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm):

`<groupId>com.oracle.em</groupId>
<artifactId>jps-ee</artifactId>`

You will also need:

`<groupId>com.oracle.em</groupId>
<artifactId>jps-api</artifactId>`