# Where does Weblogic server defines to look in ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common folder for dependecies?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

There are some libraries in ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common folder which are creating issues with our deployment (EAR). (in particular jps-ee.jar file).

How do I overwrite my weblogic server (not via web.xml) to not use the libs available (particularly jps-ee.jar) for my EAR Deployment.

We need to disable it from the weblogic end so that we can test that , this jps-ee.jar is the root cause of our issue.

So how can we do it from the weblogic end ?
And docs or steps by step guide ?

Comment: It would be easier to debug your deployment. WebLogic uses manifest class path entries extensively in it's implementation so you can't just remove/hide bits of it.

Comment: Actually, between your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933709/which-jar-on-weblogic-server-other-resources-could-possibly-have-class-oracle) and the documentation at [Manually Configuring Java EE Applications to Use OPSS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10043/devmancfg.htm#JISEC3953) I would be invoking your WebLogic support contract.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to this problem, weblogic is configured to use oralce_common using setDomainEnv.sh (or setDomainEnv.cmd based on OS)

/%ORACLE_HOME%/Middleware/user_projects/domains/%WEBLOGIC_DOMAIN%/bin/setDomainEnv.sh

This file defines the class path to be used for starting up a domain.
This file is called in by startWeblogic script to set up domain related settings.
Which loads the class paths and pass it to JVM when running the weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the weblogic server to start looking for some dependency packages from your ear/war file first, then you must use application.xml or weblogic.xml depending on whether your archive is an ear or a war.

Here is an example;

---

application.xml

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd" xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application">
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>oracle.toplink.*</package-name>
    <package-name>oracle.sql.*</package-name>
    <package-name>oracle.jdbc.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

---

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app>
    <weblogic-version>12.1.3.0.0</weblogic-version>
    <context-root>sth</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>oracle.toplink.*</package-name>
        <package-name>oracle.sql.*</package-name>
        <package-name>oracle.jdbc.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

    <prefer-application-resources>
    </prefer-application-resources>
</container-descriptor>
```

---

prefer-application-packages and prefer-application-resources are the two tools you can use for this purpose in weblogic environments. Weblogic first uses these packages in your archive file when looking a class and if not found, then it uses its embedded dependencies.

Good luck!